# Genexus 17 no inicia

Tags: genexus

Instalé Genexus 17 y no inicia, cuando va a cargar a interfaz se cierra sin dar ningún error.
Probé con la U10 y la U8 y ocurre lo mismo.

Tengo instalado Genexus 16 y funciona correctamente.

Este es el error que aparece en el visor de eventos:

> Nombre de la aplicación con errores: Genexus.exe, versión: 17.0.10.30344, marca de tiempo: 0x62b3af38
> Nombre del módulo con errores: libcef.dll, versión: 101.0.15.0, marca de tiempo: 0x626c7c1b
> Código de excepción: 0xc0000005
> Desplazamiento de errores: 0x0175bffc
> Identificador del proceso con errores: 0x1650
> Hora de inicio de la aplicación con errores: 0x01d892248931075d
> Ruta de acceso de la aplicación con errores: C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus17\Genexus.exe
> Ruta de acceso del módulo con errores: C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus17\libcef.dll
> Identificador del informe: 88c0cbc7-1b6e-4d16-b88c-99d8bafd2e04
> Nombre completo del paquete con errores:
> Identificador de aplicación relativa del paquete con errores:

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser un problema con el Proxy del Chromium (componente que se usa en Genexus).
La manera más sencilla de chequear si es eso/resolverlo es crear un archivo "chromium.proxy.disable" en el folder raíz de instalación de GeneXus.

Más info: https://www.genexus.com/es/developers/websac?data=48437;;

Comment: Creé ese archivo en el folder raíz de Genexus. Ahora al menos da un error al ratito de abrir y cuando cierro el mensaje de error se cierra Genexus.

 El mensaje de error dice lo siguiente: 

**The ChromiumWebBrowser instance creates the underlying Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF)
browser instance in an async fashin. The undelying CefBrowser instance is not yet initialized. User the
IsBrowserInitializedChanged event and check the IsBrowserInitialized prperty to determine when the
browser has been initialized. (CefSharp.WinForms)**

Comment: Ese problema lo he visto cuando querés cerrar el IDE, no al querer abrirlo. Está en https://www.genexus.com/es/developers/websac?data=50206;;
Por lo que entendí lo intentás abrir al IDE, demora y luego tira ese error... 
No se me ocurren muchas ideas salvo revisar si de esa máquina tenés conectividad a internet.

Otras posibilidades:
1. Ejecutar genexus.exe /install
2. Ver en el "event viewer de windows" si aparece más info
3. Instalar el preview del U11 que el problema original que reportaste aparece corregido (https://www.genexus.com/es/developers/downloadcenter?data=4978;;)

Comment: Actualicé a la versión Genexus 17 U11 Preview y el error sigue ocurriendo.
Tengo conexión a internet, en cambio Genexus 16 U11 me anda perfecto.

Esta es una parte del error que aparece en el visor de eventos:

Comment: Timestamp: 8/7/2022 15:42:58
Message: HandlingInstanceID: 5bc58e88-e139-4449-9c50-9823cdd0b4eb
An exception of type 'Artech.Common.Diagnostics.GxException' occurred and was caught.07/08/2022 15:42:58
Type : Artech.Common.Diagnostics.GxException, Artech.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6f5bf81c27b6b8aa
Message : The ChromiumWebBrowser instance creates the underlying Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF) browser instance in an async fashion. The undelying CefBrowser instance is not yet initialized. Use the IsBrowserInitializedChanged event and check the IsBrowserInit...